# CSS floats with equal gutters in-between

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

After many experiments I've come up with a way to add fixed, equal gutters in-between floats. My solution includes positive and negative margins and many wrappers, so it looks somewhat cumbersome. Still, I thought it's final until I realized it works only floats of equal height.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aaand/qnS2b/

I'm after this:

```
+-------------------------------+
|+---+ GUTTER +---+ GUTTER +---+|
||   |        |   |        |   ||
|+---+        +---+        +---+|
+-------------------------------+
```

The structure looks like this:

```
<div class="container-with-negative-margins">
    <div class="floated-container-with-set-width">
        <div class="container-with-positive-margins">
            <p>sample text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is some sample css:

```
.container-with-negative-margins {
    margin: -10px;
}
.floated-container-with-set-width {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}
.container-with-positive-margins {
    margin: 10px;
    /* the jsfiddle includes a fixed height and overflow: hidden, but I don't want that */
}
```

If I add content so that the `<div>`s aren't of the same height anymore, it doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works. There was a typo—wrong capitalization of class-names … The way the question was posed clearly indicated there was something wrong with the clearing of floats.

I've also updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to ruin your solution, have you tried using CSS3 type selectors?

eg:

```
div.container div {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

div.container div + div {
    margin-left: 50px; /* or 10% or whatever */
}
```

So that the 2nd, 3rd and so on elements have more margin.

Comment: I know, one could also use :first-child and :last-child. I just wanted to go a different route.

Comment: `+` is actually CSS2 combinator.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel. Just try using the not very known yet amazing [FLEX PROPERTY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

And [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you have some snippets and examples on how to use it in many scenarios, including yours.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Also, Bootstrap has something similar, using a combination of margins and paddings together with `box-sizing: border-box` (explained here http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)